# USB TO DB9 Adapter

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, serial-port, db9

I have a USB-to-DB9 adapter, no FCC serial visible anywhere, that I need drivers for.

I can't seem to get any relevant info searching on Google. Does anyone have any good ideas where I might be able to get a lead on some drivers?

I'll even upload a picture of it.

Comment: Well, drivers for which OS? :)

Comment: Windows XP who cares about the rest :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Prolific](http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/product.asp) drivers. [PL-2303](http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/downloads.asp?ID=31) is probably most common chip out there.

Comment: This solved it... awesome

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you boot from an ubuntu live cd you could do lsusb at a terminal to give you a clue

Comment: great idea too!